# How to add a new column in between existing columns?

Tags: text-processing, awk

File1.txt:

```
1 Mark USA
2 Amir UK
3 Pant USA
4 Veer IND
```

I have to add a new column

```
657890
768908
435678
342343
```

in 3rd position. So Output must be,

Output.txt

```
1 Mark 657890 USA
2 Amir 768908 UK
3 Pant 435678 USA
4 Veer 342343 IND
```

Comment: Where do `column(65.... )` entries  come from?.

Answer (score 2):

With file1.txt:

```
1 Mark USA
2 Amir UK
3 Pant USA
4 Veer IND
```

and column.txt:

```
657890
768908
435678
342343
```

do:

```bsh
$ paste file1.txt column.txt | awk '{ print $1,$2,$4,$3 }'
1 Mark 657890 USA
2 Amir 768908 UK
3 Pant 435678 USA
4 Veer 342343 IND
```

Save it by redirecting to output.txt (`> output.txt`).

Answer (score 0):

Tried by below  command and it worked fine

```
z=`awk '{print NR}' file1| sed -n '$p'`
for ((i=1;i<=$z;i++)); do j=`sed -n ''$i'p' file2`;  awk -v i="$i" -v j="$j" 'NR==i{$4=$3;$3=j;print $0}' file1; done
```

output

```
1 Mark 657890 USA
2 Amir 768908 UK
3 Pant 435678 USA
4 Veer 342343 IND
```